# How do I put data on parse.com into a variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with Ionic Framework and all the data is primarily stored on parse.com. I would like to user to be able to save some data offline and so I am writing the following function to achieve that:

```
    $scope.doSaveRow = function (_index) {
        console.log(_index);
        ParseRecipeService.get(_index).then(function (_data) {
            $timeout($scope.recipeItem = _data, 0);
        }, function (_error) {
            console.error(_error.message);
        });


        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.recipeItem));


    };
```

And here is the console output:

```
2     070531   log      [{"description":"Description Goes Here","ingredients":"Ingredients go here","instructions":"Instructions go here","picture":{"__type":"File","name":"tfss-0aa7ed68-8507-47a7-b3b0-666119d6e7f7-sando.jpg","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/5beeff27-8d26-40bb-aae0-c7429a2f7ee4/tfss-0aa7ed68-8507-47a7-b3b0-666119d6e7f7-sando.jpg"},"resources":"Resources go here","title":"Vegetable Pastry Cups","objectId":"i6jAxjvXEe","createdAt":"2015-03-19T03:01:26.726Z","updatedAt":"2015-03-23T10:56:38.951Z"},{"description":"The fourth description will go here","ingredients":"4th - ingredients go here","instructions":"Instructions for recipe #4 go here","resources":" here","title":"Fourth Recipe","objectId":"XYqNtwqGeY","createdAt":"2015-03-24T07:36:28.763Z","updatedAt":"2015-03-24T07:40:30.008Z"},{"description":"The second desciption will go here","ingredients":"ingredients for recipe #2 go here","instructions":"Instructions for recipe #2 go here","picture":{"__type":"File","name":"tfss-9c8a335a-42a6-43c3-9ef2-fa8234315955-bitcoin.png","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/5beeff27-8d26-40bb-aae0-c7429a2f7ee4/tfss-9c8a335a-42a6-43c3-9ef2-fa8234315955-bitcoin.png"},"resources":"2nd resources listed here.","title":"Second Recipe","objectId":"qj9HsDcnSi","createdAt":"2015-03-24T07:36:23.001Z","updatedAt":"2015-03-24T07:41:58.448Z"},{"description":"The third description will go here","ingredients":"third - ingredients go ther","instructions":"INstrustions for recipe #3 go here","picture":{"__type":"File","name":"tfss-67139b33-684b-414e-98d9-38d4e657c2fb-isoc-logo.png","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/5beeff27-8d26-40bb-aae0-c7429a2f7ee4/tfss-67139b33-684b-414e-98d9-38d4e657c2fb-isoc-logo.png"},"resources":"3rd resorces listed here","title":"Third Recipe","objectId":"77uRseaCsr","createdAt":"2015-03-24T07:36:25.034Z","updatedAt":"2015-03-24T07:42:10.558Z"},{"description":"The 5th description will go here","ingredients":"Ingredients go here","instructions":"Instuctions for recipe #5 go here","picture":{"__type":"File","name":"tfss-269ab33c-9de0-4895-b9f0-377ade0a6e43-feeling-station.jpg","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/5beeff27-8d26-40bb-aae0-c7429a2f7ee4/tfss-269ab33c-9de0-4895-b9f0-377ade0a6e43-feeling-station.jpg"},"resources":"1. Knife, fork, and other resources","title":"5th Recipe","objectId":"XnrNjLi08Y","createdAt":"2015-03-24T07:36:34.094Z","updatedAt":"2015-03-24T07:42:58.709Z"},{"description":"desc goes here","title":"Aurthers new recipe","objectId":"YmnmJDl9fT","createdAt":"2015-03-25T10:13:15.581Z","updatedAt":"2015-03-25T10:14:10.120Z"}]
```

Now I can see from the console printout that all my data is in the $scope.recipeItem variable but I do not know to access the information that is stored under description for example. How do I put that information in a variable? How do I then save that information offline?

Comment: Try to log only `$scope.recipeItem[0].description`..No need for stringifying.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar If I try to log only $scope.recipeItem, I get the following error: 
`8     404621   log      [object Object]
9     405128   error    TypeError: object is not a function`

Comment: Do this.. `$scope.recipeItem[0].description`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar now I'm getting this error: 

`8     606573   error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.doSaveRow (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:233:45)`

Comment: Can you share some fiddle for the problem you are facing..

Comment: Use get() to get attributes... $scope.recipeItem[0].get("description")

Comment: @danh When I try that I get the following error: `11    551576   error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.doSaveRow (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:233:45)`

Comment: @danh @Rakesh_Kumar - I've now got it to work when you use `$scope.recipeItem.get("description")`  

I've noticed a new problem. It only works when you click for the second time. The first time you click save, it gives this error `5     784495   error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.doSaveRow (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:233:42)` and when you click save the second time, it works. Any idea why? Or how to resolve that?

Comment: Add `$scope.$digest()` after you set your variable.